# Python Scikit - LinearRegression and Ridge return different results

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a small data set with 47 samples. I'm running linear regression with 2 features.

After running LinearRegression I ran Ridge (with sag). I would expect it to converge quickly, and return exactly the same prediction as computed solving the normal equations.

But every time I run Ridge I get a different result, close to the result provided by LinearRegression but not exactly the same. It doesn't matter how many iterations I run. Is this expected? Why? In the past I've implemented regular gradient descent myself and it quickly converges in this data set.

```
ols = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = ols.fit(x_train, y_train)
print(model.predict([[1650,3]]))
 %[[ 293081.4643349]]

scaler=preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(x_train)
ols = sklearn.linear_model.Ridge(alpha=0,solver="sag",max_iter=99999999,normalize=False)
model = ols.fit(x_scaled, y_train)
x_test=scaler.transform([[1650,3]])
print(model.predict(x_test))
 %[[ 293057.69986594]]
```

Comment: Assuming that you did the homework of checking the formulas and parameters, keep in mind that: (1) LinearRegression is solved in closed-form while *sag* is an iterative stochastic method. That alone often is enough to observe *small* deviations like this (as SAG's convergence is bound to hyper-params). (2) The docs ask for ```alpha>0``` while you use ```alpha=0``` (**edit** conflicting docs) which does not make sense (as LinearRegression is just the better approach then). It's often the case, that those algs somewhat collapse numerically for very small alphas (don't ask me for references)!

Comment: Sure, I agree LinearRegression is a better approach for this. I was doing this just as a learning exercise, expecting both algorithms to give the same answer. But I woudln't normally use Ridge like this.

Comment: Yeah, i'm guilty of not reading your question completely (assumed less knowledge). But yeah: SGD, SAG, and all those are not very robust and convergence is sensitive to parameters. This also applies to GD without line-search. This is experienced all the time (and of course the nature of the data matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers! After reading @sascha response I read a little bit more on Stochastic Average Gradient Descent and I think I've found the reason of this discrepancy and it seems in fact that it's due to the "stochastic" part of the algorithm.

Please check the wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent

In regular gradient descent we update the weights on every iteration based on this formula:
[image: gradient descent]

Where the second term of the sum is the gradient of the cost function multiplied by a learning rate mu.

This is repeated until convergence, and it always gives the same result after the same number of iterations, given the same starting weights.

In Stochastic Gradient Descent this is done instead in every iteration:

[image: stochastic gradient descent]

Where the second part of the sum is the gradient in **a single sample** (multiplied by the learning rate mu). All the samples are randomized at the beginning, and then the algorithm cycles through them at every iteration.

So I think a couple of things contribute to the behavior I asked about:

(EDITED see replies below)

1. The point used to calculate the gradient at every iteration changes every time I re-run the fit function. That's why I don't obtain the same result every time.

(EDIT)(This can be made deterministic by using **random_state** when calling the fit method)

1. I also realized that the number of iterations that the algorithm runs varies between 10 and 15 (regardless of the max_limit I set). I couldn't find anywhere what the criteria for convergence is in scikit, but my guess is that if I could tighten it (i.e. run for more iterations) the answer I would get would be much closer to the LinearRegression method.

(EDIT)(Convergence criteria depends on **tol** (precision of the solution). By modifying this parameter (I set it to 1e-100) I was able to obtain the same solution as the one reported by LinearRegression)

Comment: (1) This is deterministic if you would use the ```random_state``` argument. (2) [Convergence-crits are seen here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/linear_model/sag_fast.pyx#L492): so you would want to play with ```tol``` param. (Additional) While SGD/SAGA all only converge on some conditions, it still applies to GD too. If you don't do line-search there and the learning-rate does not comply to the hessian of the opt-problem, there will be no convergence to the local/global-opt.

Comment: Thank you @sascha. 1) Yes, I see now that after setting random_state to some number the regression always returns the same results after the same number of iterations, as expected. 2) Setting the tol parameter to a very low number gives the expected result!: [[ 293081.4643349]], exactly the same as LinearRegression.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your two different outputs may come from your preprocessing that you only do for the Ridge regression :`scaler=preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(x_train)`.

By doing such normalization you change the representation of your data and it may lead to different results.

Note also the fact that by doing [OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) you penalize the L2 norm looking only at the output differences (expected vs predicted) while [Ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) the algorithm's also taking into account the input match or mismatch

Comment: Why should Ridge use both norms?`That does not sound correct.

Comment: My understanding is that the normalization is done when using some sort of gradient descent to obtain a faster convergence. In any case, I tried removing the regularization and I observe the same behavior.
Also, Ridge only penalizes L2, and normalizes the coefficients by the factor alpha. In this case I'm setting it to zero, so it should give the return the same value as OLS.

Comment: @sascha penalizing L1 norm too, will improve the sparsity of your data and the regularization will be done without considering small quantities or, more generally, non relevant piece of data. This can lead to better generalization

Comment: @nsaura Yes, but that's not Ridge anymore (as seen in your own wiki-link)!

Comment: @Fackelmann my point was that both your data representation and your algorithm are different. So it is almost expected to have different results.

Comment: @nsaura It really doesn't. If I obtain an absolute minimum for the cost function, it shouldn't matter whether I've normalized or not, as long as I normalize the data i want to fit to get a prediction later on. In fact, if I implemented regular gradient descent, I can assure you that both results will be exactly the same (given that gradient descent runs for enough iterations to converge), even if I do normalization in the second case.

Comment: @sascha you are absolutely right I mixed up with Lasso regression I will edit my post thank you 
But my point still holds because in Ridge you improve sparsity by taking into account the input match, like a RBF kernel.

Comment: And in any case, just to clear all doubts, I just tested regularizing  the data I input to LinearRegression and I obtain the same result as without regularization. And in this case the input to Ridge and LinearRegression is identical.

Comment: @Fackelmann if the algorithm doesn't change your training score, then your different results come from the normalization. It is possible that without your pre-processing, your algorithm (regardless the cost function) gets stuck into a local minimum (close to the global).
For example scaling your data in Neural network algorithm normally leads to better results

Comment: @nsuara This is what I'm doing now, just to check after reading your answers:

1) Normalize data
2) Train LogisticRegression with normalized data
3) Train Ridge with normalized data

So both LogisticRegression and Ridge have exactly the same input data. I still see the same behavior I described in my original post. I cannot agree with you that normalization is the cause of this behavior.

Comment: @nsaura Ridge is strictly convex. Every local-minimum is a global-minimum.

Comment: Well regarding scipy's code they imposed alpha strictly positive as @sascha pointed out : "    alpha : {float, array-like},
        shape = [n_targets] if array-like
        Regularization strength; must be a positive float. Regularization
        improves the conditioning of the problem and reduces the variance of
        the estimates."

I didn't go further in their algorithm but I suggest you to have a look https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py I hope it will help